# Are there concrete benefits to injecting Controllers with Data opposed to injecting Controllers with Model?

Tags: php, oop, model-view-controller, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

My goal of asking this question is to ferret out whether there are benefits to injecting Controller directly with the data it needs (more specific approach) opposed to injecting a Model into a Controller (more generic approach).  Or to establish whether or not it is *just a matter of preference*.

**Injecting Controller with Model:**

Model can be used to run all kinds of queries to retrieve various bits of data, but it is a heavier-weight construct than the data itself.  Model essentially contains data, or at least it can access all the data you may need.  Example:

```
class CategoryControllerWithModel
{
    private $model;

    public function __construct($model)
    {
        $this->model = $model;
    }

    // generates HTML for input form
    public function genHtml()
    {
        /* retrieve data */
        $categories = $this->model->getCategories();

        //...
    }
}

//instantiation within Factory Method:
class Factory
{
    $model = new CategoryModel();
    $controller = new CategoryControllerWithModel($model);
    return $controller;
}
```

**Injecting Controller with Data:**

Here we do a bit more upfront with in the Factory method but we get a leaner Controller that only receives exactly the data it needs and is so completely separated from the Model that it is not even aware of its existence.

```
class CategoryControllerWithData
{
    private $categories;

    public function __construct($categories)
    {
        $this->categories = $categories;
    }

    public function genHtml()
    {
        $categories = $this->categories;
    }
}

//instantiation within Factory Method:
class Factory
{
    $model = new CategoryModel();

    //a bit more work to get the data Controller needs
    //benefit:  Controller not tied to the Model
    $categories = $model->getCategories():

    $controller = new CategoryControllerWithData($categories);
    return $controller;
}
```

**Question:**

I suppose MVC stands for exactly that -- Model, View, Controller, so injecting Model is probably considered to be an "okay" thing to do.  If so, am I taking this too far by trying to remove Controller dependency on Model?

Suppose I insist that I want to inject Data into my Controllers rather than the Model.  Is this a purely preferential issue do you see any concrete benefits of doing so?

Answer (score 1):

From my point of view, Factory shouldn't be responsible for domain logic. It should only be responsible for building things up.

In this case, where you are injecting data, Factory has to know what categories controller is searching for, are there any filtering and so on.

So I think for controller you should only inject model, keep Factory single responsibility only for building things and controller should be responsible for it's data.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a matter of "separation of concerns" also I do not think that would be a good example of using MVC. I would think more along these lines:

```
class FooController
{
    public function actionView($alias){
        $category = Category::loadByAlias($alias);
        ..... load and render layouts etc .....
    }

    public function actionList(){
        $categories = Category::loadAll();
        ..... etc ......
    }
}
```

like this the neither the Controller nor the Factory need to know what needs to be done when you load a category nor do they have to handle active/inactive status, even User access ... etc this is all Model Logic, Model can have beforeLoad and afterLoad functions, conditions for listing all categories, eager or lazy loading of related models etc...